# form validation in js

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am working on validating forms am not sure if I am making it more complicated than it needs to be. I have a variable that i'm comparing the element to and then on success replacing a img src with a check for success or x for failure. It is supposed to run my validateData function once the field is unfocused. Here is the js. My img src src does not change when I test the first field by putting in numbers to trigger the redx.png src change.

```js
function validateData() {
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var image1=document.getElementsById("image1");

  if (document.forms["quiz_form"]["last_name"].value.match(letters) && document.forms["quiz_form"]["last_name"].value!="")
  {
    image1.src="check.png";
  }
  else{
    image1.src="redx.png";
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="author" content="Kenneth Dunn" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <script src="quiz.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="quiz.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
      <div id="logo">
        <h1><a href="https://playoverwatch.com">Overwatch</a></h1>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <h2>Overwatch Quiz</h2>
        <p>
          Hi there!
          This quiz is dedicated to one of my favorite games Overwatch! 
        </p>
        <form action="quiz.js" method="post" name="quiz_form">
          <p><br>
            <input name "first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name"   onblur="this.placeholder='First Name'" onfocus="this.placeholder='Use only letters'" onblur="validateData()"/>
            <img src='http://www.q-park.ie/Portals/8/images/search-icon.png' id="image1" class="image1"/>
          </p>

          <p><br>
            <input name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name"  onblur="this.placeholder='Last Name'" onfocus="this.placeholder='Use only Letters'" onblur="validateData()" />
            <img src='http://www.q-park.ie/Portals/8/images/search-icon.png' id="image2" class="image2"/>
          </p>

          <p><br>
            <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email"  onblur="this.placeholder='Email'" onfocus="this.placeholder='Must contain @ '" onblur="validateData()"/>
            <img src='http://www.q-park.ie/Portals/8/images/search-icon.png' id="image3" class="image3"/>
          </p>

          <p><br>
            <input name="number" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" onblur="this.placeholder='Phone Number'" onfocus="this.placeholder='Must follow xxx-xxx-xxx '" onblur="validateData()" />
            <img src='http://www.q-park.ie/Portals/8/images/search-icon.png' id="image4" class="image4"/>
          </p>

          <p><br>
            <input name="sulley" type="text" placeholder="Sulley Email" onblur="this.placeholder='Sulley Email Address'" onfocus="this.placeholder='Must contain ~ and https:// '" onblur="validateData()" />
            <img src='http://www.q-park.ie/Portals/8/images/search-icon.png' id="image5" class="image5"/>
          </p>
          <br>
          <br>
          <p>

          <h2>Find out which Overwatch character you are most like!</h2>

          <p>If you could pick what form to take in a fictional universe with magic and cool science what would you want to be?</p>

          <input type="radio" name="exist" value="1">Male(Human).<br>
          <input type="radio" name="exist" value="2">Female(Human).<br>
          <input type="radio" name="exist" value="3">An Animal or something crazy.

          <p>What is your preferred weapon to take on bad guys and defend yourself?</p>

          <input type="radio" name="weapon" value="1">Twin Shotguns for close range.<br>
          <input type="radio" name="weapon" value="2">Twin pistols medium range.<br>
          <input type="radio" name="weapon" value="3">An electro gun that schocks enemies into submission.

          <p>Which motivations most align with your own?<p>

          <input type="radio" name="idea" value="1">To become more powerful and to defeat those who would oppose me.<br>
          <input type="radio" name="idea" value="2">To explore the world and discover the unknown.<br>
          <input type="radio" name="idea" value="3">To protect my friends and those I care about.

          <p>What do you look like?</p>

          <input type="radio" name="look" value="1">Dark and mysterious black-hooded figure ,very edgy, like people in the Matix.<br>
          <input type="radio" name="look" value="2">Short and spunky British airforce pilot who can travel back in time.<br>
          <input type="radio" name="look" value="3">I'm a large gorilla who likes to eat bananas and peanut butter and can sheild my friends from harm. 

          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
          <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
          </p>
        </form>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

      <div id="footer">
        <h2 align="center" >Created by </h2>
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question? Where is your HTML?

Comment: @CarlMarkham The img src does not change when testing, and I am not sure why. I have updated it to add my html.

Comment: You've got two onblur="" on each input. You shouldn't handle placeholder text with JS, use the placeholder="Some Text" attribute for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just simply set the `action` to your JS script, you will need to use the `onsubmit` event handler.

```html
<form onsubmit="validateData">
```

This will trigger the `validateData` method once the form is submitted. This won't stop the form from performing as usual though, you will need to stop that in your `validateData` method like so:

```
function validateData (event) {
  // prevent the form from actually submitting
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Is there no way I can use onblur to run the validation in real time on the page?

Comment: I have the submit button for a separate portion of the site, I do not wish to use it for the validation, Just dynamically display an img based on correct or incorrect inputs checked in the form validation.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here; some have been mentioned by others.  One of the main problems is you had `getElementsById` instead of `getElementById`.  If you haven't figured out how to pull up the developer console and see what errors you're getting, now would be a good time.

Form validation can get pretty complicated and normally I use a library that does the heavy lifting.  You might look into that.

Here is a working version of what I'm guessing you're trying to do.  It's far from optimal but it's what I was quickly able to come up with.

https://jsfiddle.net/ec2L08vf/1/

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will look over what I wrote again to fix this issue, as a side note I was trying to pull the jsfiddle code and put it into my existing .html and .js file for testing and it does operate as it did in jsfiddle, is there something I am missing?

Comment: I'm guessing there's a bug in your existing code that's stopping javascript. open the console and look.

Comment: I checked, nothing in the console, when I put it in script tags in the html page it worked, but externally on my local machine, it did not. Maybe has to do with not being uploaded to a live site.

Comment: the html needs <html></html> and <script type="text/javascript" src="scriptFile.js"> </script>